# helm: retrieve the version of a plugin in a template

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, cert-manager

I'd like to retrieve the apiversion of a given plugin, for instance certmanager, programmatically within an helm template file.Basically the third column of the output of:

```
[xx@xx-bnng5g3 test]$ kubectl api-resources -o wide | grep certificates      
certificates                      cert,certs       cert-manager.io/v1         true    Certificate
```

I was thinking of achieving the result using a `(lookup ...)` but I am finding more difficult than expected. Is there any simpler way to do that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That column shows the `apiVersion:` value that would be used in Kubernetes resources.  In Kubernetes API terminology, it is the combination of a *group* and *version*.

In Helm, there is a [built-in `.Capabilities` object](https://docs.helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/builtin_objects/) that includes details about the API versions available.  You can test for a specific version:

```yaml
{{- if .Capabilities.APIVersions.Has "cert-manager.io/v1" }}
apiVersion: cert-manager.io/v1
kind: Certificate
...
{{- end }}
```

Finding the current version(s) of a particular API group is more challenging.  `.Capabilities.APIVersions` appears to be a simple list of strings and you could search that using any of the standard [list](https://masterminds.github.io/sprig/lists.html) or [list-of-string functions](https://masterminds.github.io/sprig/string_slice.html).  This does not include anything like Unix **grep**(1) that could find strings that begin with a particular prefix, alas.

(This technique can be useful for upgrading from a beta to a released version of a Kubernetes API.  When `apps/v1beta1` Deployment objects were removed from Kubernetes, for example, some older clusters did not yet support `apps/v1` Deployments yet.  This makes it possible to say, if a `v1` version is available, use it, and if not, use the older `v1beta1` version.)